# compare date with millisecond in android

Tags: java, android, time, milliseconds, android-date

I have date in this format **"23-March-2003"** and time in **milliseconds** which include **date+time**.

Now I want compare this **date** with **millisecond** either it is same date or not. how can I do this??

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @njzk2 date+time is converted into milliseconds, now compare the date and milliseconds

Comment: still don't understand what you precisely mean by those being the same data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this might work: (It is good practice to use `Calendar`)

```
private boolean areEqual(String theDate, long currentTimeMillis) {
    try {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(theDate));
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(new Date(currentTimeMillis));
        return ((c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
                &&
           (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
boolean result = areEqual("23-March-2003", System.currentTimeMillis());
```